Biomejs won't address CSS files
I'm using biomejs for some tooling on a project. It ignores my CSS files, and I'm not sure why.
biome.json in the root of my project
{
  "$schema": "https://biomejs.dev/schemas/1.8.3/schema.json",
  "css": {
    "formatter": {
      "enabled": true,
      "indentWidth": 2,
      "indentStyle": "space"
    }
  }
}


I use VSCode. I do have the biomejs extension enabled, and biome set as my default formatter. It handles my JS/TS/JSON files but ignores CSS files. My VSCode status bar says "Biome 1.8.3 the current file is not supported or ignored by Biome".
CSS linting/formatting support is "in-progress" for biome--according to their docs--however it parses CSS for my coworkers on their machines. I can't figure out whats up in my case.

That was probably a bug. The latest version should work now.
